# JavaScript Object Sort method

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

In the compareNumeric fn I dont understand this concept with comparison. 
To see more detailed: if (5 > 3) return 1; So what is this return 1 and return -1; how does it work, and how does it affect on sort method. Please , help me out!

```
function compareNumeric(a, b) {
  if (a > b) return 1;
  if (a < b) return -1;
}

var arr = [ 1, 2, 15, 14, 66, 434, 112, 3 ];

arr.sort(compareNumeric);

alert(arr);  // sorted array
```

Comment: you might have a look here: [`Array#sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

Answer (score 1):

[MDN's documentation for `Array.prototype.sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort?v=control) will help. Basically, `sort` calls the callback repeatedly, with various combinations of two entries from the array. The callback's return value tells `sort` whether 1) `a` should be before of `b` in the result (by returning a negative value), or 2) `a` should be after `b` in the result (by returning a positive value), or 3) `a` and `b` are equivalent for sorting purposes so it doesn't matter (by returning 0).

Your example `compareNumeric` has a bug: It should return `0` if `a` is neither `<` nor `>` `b`, but instead it doesn't return anything, so calling it results in `undefined`. Instead:

```
function compareNumeric(a, b) {
    if (a > b) { return 1; }
    if (a < b) { return -1; }
    return 0;
}
```

**But**, it has another problem: It never checks whether `a` and `b` are actually numeric. If the author is happy to *assume* they're numeric, it can be a simpler function:

```
function compareNumeric(a, b) {
    return a - b;
}
```

If both `a` and `b` are numbers, then `a - b` will be negative if `a` is less than `b` and so should be before it in the result, positive if `a` is greater than `b` and so should be after it in the result, or `0` if `a` and `b` are equal.

Note that the number of times the callback gets called and in what order are not defined by the specification; all it says is that `Array#sort` will call the callback as necessary and use the resulting information.

Let's watch what arguments `Array#sort` gives with your example; again note that this will be implementation-dependent:

```js
function compareNumeric(a, b) {
  if (a > b) return 1;
  if (a < b) return -1;
  return 0;
}

var arr = [ 1, 2, 15, 14, 66, 434, 112, 3 ];

arr.sort(function(a, b) {
  var result = compareNumeric(a, b);
  console.log("a = " + a + ", b = " + b + "; returning " + result);
  return result;
});

console.log(arr.join());  // sorted array
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```